# Linux WiFi connection disconnected due to inactivity

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

Recently my WiFi connection keeps disconnected/connected like in a loop several times a day while i'm actively working.

I tried a lot of options:

1. Contacted support team for my router's brand. They suggest several configuration options  which didn't work. They also confirm that disconnections were initiated by my machine, so I keep searching for the issue on my side.
2. Checked twice that I got WiFi power management disabled
3. Did some tweaks to WiFi driver iwlwifi.
4. Tried to increase the WiFi signal with another WiFi spot.

Issue still persist.

**Q: What can be the reason of this disconnections and how can I fix this issue? What's the `reason 4: Disassociated due to inactivity` actually means?**

`iw event` log:

```
wlp3s0 (phy #0): connected to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
wlp3s0 (phy #0): CQM event: RSSI went above threshold
wlp3s0: del station xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
wlp3s0 (phy #0): deauth yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy -> xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx reason 4: Disassociated due to inactivity [frame: frame data]
wlp3s0 (phy #0): disconnected (local request) reason: 4: Disassociated due to inactivity                                                             
phy #0: regulatory domain change: set to world roaming by the wireless core upon initialization request
wlp3s0 (phy #0): scan started
wlp3s0 (phy #0): scan finished: 2412 2417 2422 2427 2432 2437 2442 2447 2452 2457 2462 2467 2472 5180 5200 5220 5240 5260 5280 5300 5320 5500 5520 5540 5560 5580 5600 5620 5640 5660 5680 5700 5720 5745 5765 5785 5805 5825, "myssid" ""
wlp3s0: new station xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
wlp3s0 (phy #0): auth xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx -> yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy status: 0: Successful [frame: here goes frame data]
wlp3s0 (phy #0): assoc xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx -> yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy status: 0: Successful [frame: here goes frame data]
wlp3s0 (phy #0): connected to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
wlp3s0 (phy #0): CQM event: RSSI went above threshold
wlp3s0: del station xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
wlp3s0 (phy #0): deauth yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy -> xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx reason 4: Disassociated due to inactivity [frame: frame data again]
wlp3s0 (phy #0): disconnected (local request) reason: 4: Disassociated due to inactivity
phy #0: regulatory domain change: set to world roaming by the wireless core upon initialization request
wlp3s0 (phy #0): scan started
wlp3s0 (phy #0): scan finished: 2412 2417 2422 2427 2432 2437 2442 2447 2452 2457 2462 2467 2472 5180 5200 5220 5240 5260 5280 5300 5320 5500 5520 5540 5560 5580 5600 5620 5640 5660 5680 5700 5720 5745 5765 5785 5805 5825, "myssid" ""
wlp3s0: new station xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
wlp3s0 (phy #0): auth xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx -> yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy status: 0: Successful [frame: frame data]
wlp3s0 (phy #0): assoc xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx -> yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy status: 0: Successful [frame: frame data indeed]
wlp3s0 (phy #0): connected to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

Comment: If it's due to inactivity, then use the WiFi continually. For example, you could run an app to ping a site, e.g. Microsoft, every 10 minutes. There are tools to do this such as https://download.cnet.com/KeepAlive/3000-2381_4-10734461.html , though I've not used them.

Comment: Well, I heavily use my network in the moment when the issue appers. I also set infinite ping in separate terminal, disconnects still happens.

Comment: Hello there, what's the model of your Wireless access point / router in use? Does the router / access point have settings for features such as "congestion control", etc, and if so, are they enabled?

Comment: @DennisMungai Hello! It's Mikrotik cAP lite, well, I have no idea, actually. I had a look in the administration panel and didn't see anything common.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I tried :) that didn't work. I also sit right next to the AP and still got the issue.

Comment: This issue is because the wlan driver is detecting missed acknowledgements from the access point. It could be a driver issue, it could be a hardware issue... What's the make/model of the access point? What's the model if the intel WLAN adapter using iwlwifi? You may be able to tweak this behavior with the IW command, it really depends on the capabilities of the adapter in question.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart It's Mikrotik cAP lite and Intel 7260. I tried some options for the adapter such as `11n_disable=1` and `11n_disable=8`, but that didn't solve the issue.